# Sails error, when I try to update session to redis

Tags: docker, redis, sails.js

I try to deploy sails code to **docker** (using docker-compose), BUT **I got error** with redis config in docker

#### config file

```
session: {
    adapter: '@sailshq/connect-redis',
    url: 'redis://:password@localhost:6379/1'
}
```

#### docker-compose file [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TVuWij5W)

```
version: '3'
services: 
    cachedb:
    image: redis
    restart: always
stag:
    build: .
    command: 'yarn start:stag' # NODE_ENV=staging node app.js
    ports:
        - '8000:1337'
    depends_on:
        - cachedb
```

#### Error text [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2xBM1nKK)

```
AbortError: Connection forcefully ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.
at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:350:23)
at RedisClient.end (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/node_modules/redis/lib/extendedApi.js:51:14)
at RedisClient.onPreConnectionEnd (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/machines/get-connection.js:157:14)
at RedisClient.emit (events.js:180:13)
at RedisClient.connection_gone (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:578:14)
at RedisClient.on_error (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:398:10)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/base/node_modules/machinepack-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:272:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

### Version

- OS: macOS 10.13.4 17E199 x86_64 MacBookPro11,4
- Shell: zsh 5.3
- Terminal: iTerm2
- Node: v9.10.1
- Npm: 5.6.0
- Yarn: 1.5.1 (USE)
- Sails: 1.0.0
- Other: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0t9dBAXY)

### Ref

1. Full docker config: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TVuWij5W)
2. Error log: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2xBM1nKK)
3. Yarn.lock: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0t9dBAXY)

Comment: Were you able to fix this? im getting the same error. Was it something to do with the ca-certificate file?